# Postponing Date of Joining by New Employer

Tags: covid-19, onboarding

I received an offer letter for a new position with a new employer. I handed in my resignation to my previous employer, and served out my two months notice period.

After my last day at my previous company, the new company informed me that they needed to postpone my onboarding for a week due to the Coronavirus lockdown. The lockdown was extended beyond that week so I requested a virtual onboarding, however that did not occur. It's been 4 months and they have still not provided a Date of Joining, and when questioned they replied saying that they can't give specific joining date and I will have to wait - but nobody knows how long the wait will be.

What can I do now?

Comment: In which country does this happen? I assume you have a signed work contract with a start date given in the contract?

Comment: What is your country and why don't you disclose it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has been four months.  If you are not already doing so, you should be searching for new opportunities.  You could even try to return to your former employer if that is a possibility.  It is anyone's guess when ( if ) you will join the new company, but if you are currently without work and without income, you should be looking for work instead of waiting for something that may never happen.

Comment: But do they have the right to delay so long once I resign? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Whether or not they have that right is up to your local laws, you would need to seek the advice of a lawyer to see what your legal options are.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.

Comment: If possible, (depending on country) you should try to claim unemployment benefits.

Comment: @R37, "Is there anything I can do about it?" It completely depends on the country you're located in. Not know that crucial bit of information. We can't tell you.